# How do you interpret probabilities?

Tags: probability

I am a college student, and i have been doin probabilities since 4 years and I always had one question which puzzled me.... Its like this :

If i were told to  find the probability of getting a head in a single toss of a coin ,the answer is pretty easy right? Its 1/2.
But i cant  interpret this answer logically. like does it mean  1 out of every 2 two tosses of the coin would be a head ( which is so obvoiusly false ) or does it mean that my chances of getting a heads is like 'half'. What im tryin to say is i really cant find any real life significance  of the concept of probability.  Can anyone help me out, please?

P.S.: THNX PEOPLE, ithink i have a fairly good idea now, mainly from *the frequentist interpretation*

Comment: It is the average number of heads per flip.

Comment: You are not alone! There has been for many years vigorous philosophical and technical debate about the *meaning* of probability. But there is nearly universl agreement about the *usefulness* of the concept.

Comment: Probability is neither easy nor intuitive.  You might want to read Jordan Ellenberg's (expository, mass-audience) book *How Not to be Wrong*.  It talks a lot about the quirks of probability.  Among them: how badly named the *expected value* is.  The number of heads in 10 tosses of a coin has expected value 5, but you shouldn't necessarily expect 5 heads.

Comment: There are different interpretations of probability. The frequentist view is something like "if you throw a flip a large number of coins, 1/2 of them will be heads". Basically, the probability of an outcome is the fraction of times it appears in a large number of trials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to the ideal fair coin, the probability that heads is 0.5 means that for any given flip, there is exactly equal chance you will see heads or tails. In reality, you can (and with enough flips, will) see any and every sequence. But when you add up the total number of heads, and divide it by the total number of flips, you will have a sequence that approaches 0.5 in the limit due to the [strong law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Forms).

Comment: @Lakhi: For much more detail about the viewpoint described by Avraham, please search under *frequentist interpretation of probability*. This is the most common current interpretation.There are others.

Answer (score 0):

There is another interpretation, called the Bayesian interpretation.
Probability can be defined as the degree to which it is reasonable to believe in an event happening based on intuition, experience, judgment, and opinion. A probability of one means that you're certain it will happen, and a probability of zero means you're certain it won't happen.

If the probability of heads is 1/2, according to this interpretation, you're saying that it's just as reasonable to believe heads with occur as it is reasonable to believe tails will occur.